# Pivot Syntax Error in SQL , Why am I getting Incorrect results?

Tags: sql, pivot

Someone please help me understand what is wrong in this Pivot syntax ?
Thanks @Ross Bush for fixing my query but I am not getting desired output, I want PersonFK values in the rows but after executing below query, output is something like this -

[image]

This is the original table -

[image]

RequisitionID (int, not null)
RoleCode (nvarchar(100), not null)
PersonFK (int, null)

```
SELECT RequisitionID,
   1 AS One,
   2 AS Two,
   3 AS Three
FROM
(SELECT RequisitionID,
      RoleCode,
      PersonFK
  FROM RequisitionHiringTeam
  WHERE RoleCode IN (1,
                  2,
                  3)) as src 
  PIVOT (
  max(PersonFK) 
  FOR RoleCode 
  IN ([1],[2],[3])
) as pvt
GO
```

Comment: Please tag it with the database engine you are using.

Comment: Please don't post  [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your code and data, no one can test an image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using column aliases like that I you need them in brackets ->

```
SELECT
    ...[1] As One, [2] As Two..
FROM
(
 <query>)as src
PIVOT( 
...
FOR RoleCode IN
IN ([1],[2],[3])
)as pvt
```

Comment: Thanks ! that resolved the error, but I am not getting the desired Output.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my query and it gave me desired result =

```
SELECT RequisitionID,
   [1] AS One,
   [2] AS Two,
   [3] AS Three
FROM
(SELECT RequisitionID,
      RoleCode,
      PersonFK
 FROM RequisitionHiringTeam
) src 
PIVOT (
  SUM(PersonFK) 
  FOR RoleCode 
  IN ([1],[2],[3])
)pvt
GO
```

I need to put [ ... ] for columns in the first select statement. Output =

[image]